# Create Team Graph Api fails if I am on Teams Call

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, rest

Sometimes, when I use the Create Team graph api call while I am on a Teams call with multiple people, although the API succeeds, either the group isn't created  have to quit the call and wait for a couple of minutes for the group to show or the group isnt created at all.

This never happens when I am not on a Teams call.

Is there a fix to this issue?

Create Team Api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This problem is seen in the beta version of create team (where you don't need office 365 group) as well.

Comment: It might be related to this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62895437/installing-microsoft-teams-app-using-graph-api-is-taking-more-time

Comment: Can you confirm that if you stay on call then the new team is never created ?

Comment: Although not always, but sometimes it defintley isn't created till the call is over. And when that happens, it usually takes more than 30 minutes for the team to show on my screen after I leave the call.

Comment: @Confused, Graph Team can take some time to propagate, which is expected behavior. Anyways I am going to discuss this issue with internal team.